# Keras simple feed-forward network input shape error

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to train a very simple feed forward network in Keras. I want to give the network 1800 numbers, and have it activate 1 of 6 outputs.

My model is set up as follows:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(256, input_dim = 1800, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(48, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(6, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

My data is set up as follows:

It is split into two Python lists `training_data` and `training_labels`.

An element from `training_labels` is a Python list containing 6 numbers like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

An element from `training_data` is a Python list containing 1800 numbers like this:

```
[15, 155, 1200, 1, ... ]
```

There are 1500 examples in total.

To fit the model, I am doing:

```
model.fit(training_data, training_labels, batch_size=1)
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (None, 1800) but got array with shape (150, 1)
```

Comment: *"but got array with shape (150, 1)"*. You're not feeding what you think you're feeding as data

Comment: Print out `training_data.shape`. The `training_data` doesn't have the shape you assume it has

Comment: `training_data` is a Python list with 1500 elements. Each element is a list containing 1800 integers. `len(training_data)` returns 1500, and I can assert that the length of each list inside is 1800.

Comment: Try reshaping the data training_data=np.reshape(1500,1800)

Comment: I am using Python lists, not NumPy. I will convert into a NumPy array and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what have mentioned, I suggest to add one line before feeding the data into your network:

```
import numpy as np

training_data = np.asarray(training_data)
assert(training_data.shape = (1500,1800))
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you probably have a misunderstanding regarding the shape of your data. To prove that, check out the code snipped below.

```
import numpy as np

training_data = np.random.rand(1500, 1800)
training_labels = np.ones((1500, 6))
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(256, input_dim = 1800, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(48, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(6, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_data, training_labels, batch_size=1)
```

This model compiles and trains.

Comment: Nice, clean, and reproducible answer (+1)